# Local host VS ip address in ASP.net

Tags: c#

i run one aspx webpage , in url it have some thing like http://localhost:1481/Tutorial/MainPage.aspx . But when i change the localhost in to my IP Address the page can't display . Please guide me to get this .Thanks in advance..

Comment: There are steps to do this, but it would be easier if you put the error you get in your question.

Comment: Just it displays "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".. Nothing else

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio built-in Web Werver only listens on the loop back address 127.0.0.1 which translates to LOCALHOST in your PC's host file

you can add entries into your host file to allow different names to resolve to loop back but not change the loop back address

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the VS testing server? I believe it only listens on the loopback.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also including the port number in the URL when you use your IP address?